# Mendel Kernel Live Patching

Tags: security, linux-kernel, google-coral, automatic-updates

Is there a way to live patch the kernel on Mendel? I'm looking to deploy the coral dev kit and need a way to ensure that it is up to date with the latest kernel security updates.

It looks like the only current way to do so is to re-flash the board. If it is not possible to have a live patch, can you explain why?

Answer (score -1):

You can update the kernel and or modules without re-flashing the entire boards.

Comment: If this is case, how come it is not possible to upgrade from Mendel release day to release eagle without re-flashing?